# How to sum parts of a column?

Tags: r, sum

I am doing a project on working out Flashiness index for a 15-minute flow data.
I have got code on how to work out flow data.

```
# new variable for lag time
flow_lagged_S <- S %>% mutate(
flow_lag = lag(flow, n = 1), #1st claculate lag 
Qi_Qi1 = abs(flow - flow_lag))# calculate the abs value of the diff
# calculate sums following the formula
RB_index_S <- flow_lagged_S %>%
summarise(RB_index = sum(,Qi_Qi1, na.rm = T) / sum(flow, na.rm = T))
```

The data is for different years and at the moment I can calculate the flashiness for the whole station but not for ever year.
For the last bit of the code I need to change it so that it calculates the sum for each year. How do I do that? so instead of the whole column Qi_Qi1 i need t sum Qi_Qi1 for year 2002.
so my table flow_lagged_S looks like this:

```
time_stamp           flow    year  flow_lag  Qi_Qi1
2002-10-24 22:45:00   9.50   2002   N/A       N/a
2002-10-24 23:00:00  10.00   2002   9.50      0.50
2002-10-24 23:15:00   10.50   2002   10.00    0.50
2002-10-24 23:30:00  11.00   2002   10.50     0.70
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use group_by() function from dplyr package:

```
df <- data.frame(time_stamp = c("2002-10-24 22:45:00", "2002-10-24 23:00:00", "2002-10-24 23:15:00", "2002-10-24 23:30:00"),
    flow = c(9.5, 10, 10.5, 11),
    year = c(2002, 2002, 2002, 2002), 
    flow_lag = c(NA, 9.5, 10, 10.5), 
    Qi_Qi = c(NA, .5, .5, .7))

df %>%
    group_by(year) %>%
    summarize(total = sum(Qi_Qi, na.rm = T))
```

The answer is:

```
# A tibble: 1 x 2
   year total
  <dbl> <dbl>
1  2002   1.7
```

Comment: Ah okay. Thank you so much but I have like 10000s of data for that year and I am very new to Rstudio. Do I do the same?

Comment: Of course. You just need to group by 'year' and summarize like I did. It will end up with the total (sum) of your desired column (variable).